# How to write for loop in python code into a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

In this code I have tried to read csv files and find the total pass and fail and have to insert the second for loop segment into a csv file.

````
    d=dfs[i]['Filename'].tolist()
    total=len(dfs[i].IngestionStatus)
    tpass=len(dfs[i][dfs[i]['IngestionStatus'] == 'Pass']) 
    tfail=total-tpass
    print ("SNo\t\tName\t\tTotal\t\tTotalPass\t\tTotalFail")
    print ("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    for j in range(1):
        print ("%d:\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%d" % (j,d[j] ,total,tpass,tfail))
    print ("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")```

Need to convert this section of the code into a table and insert it into a csv file
````

Comment: Is this what you need https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: I wanted it to be written to a .csv file

Comment: you are using tab delimitted in your string. If you want to write to csv file it would be https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/writing-csv-files